# mass removal of rows from a data frame based on a column condition

Tags: r

I would like to remove all rows based on a condition of a column. The code below produces a sample test data

`test_data <- data.frame(index = c(1,2,3,4,5), group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "c"), count = c(1,2,2,3,4))`

The data frame has 3 columns: index, group and count. I would like to remove all rows belonging to the same group if any one row of the group has count 1. So in above data frame, I would like to remove entire index 1, 2 and 3 from data frame since first row has count = 1 and row 2nd and 3rd fall in the same group "a". The resultant data frame should look like this:

```
testdata2 <- data.frame(index = c(4,5), group = c("b", "c"), count = c(3,4))
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: hi you can use ```subset``` to get result ```testdata2 <- subset(test_data,!test_data$group=='a')``` hope this will help

Comment: Thanks @Tushar..but there are many groups like this. I have just shown a sample data. So I don't just have to remove just one group ("a" in this example), but all rows of any group that has associated count 1. I cannot hard code a group as there are many groups with this condition. Also, I have to put a condition that if test$count = 1, remove all rows falling in the same group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave` with `subset` in base R and select groups which has no value where `count` is 1.

```
subset(test_data, ave(count != 1, group, FUN = all))

#  index group count
#4     4     b     3
#5     5     c     4
```

With `dplyr` this can be done as :

```
library(dplyr)
test_data %>% group_by(group) %>% filter(all(count != 1))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_data)[, .SD[all(count != 1)], group]
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak, but will the above code only remove those rows that have count = 1? I also want to remove that fall in the same group but can have any count. For instance, if first row 's count = 1, remove the first row but also remove 2nd and 3rd rows because they belong to the same group as 1st row.

Comment: @Stats No this will remove all the rows for the group even if there is 1 value where `count = 1`. See for example `test_data` and `group` "a", it removes all the 3 rows and not only 1st row. Did you try the answer? It gives the same expected output as shown in `testdata2`.